# how to make auto reaction discord.js

Tags: discord.js

basically what im trynna do here is if u have used carl bot you may know you can make it so on a message(for example a ping) it would react with message of ur choice, I'm trynna basically do that and heres what ive tried

```
    if (lowerCaseMessage === messagetoReact) {
  message.react('')
```

}

```
and in my config file
"messagestoReact" : ["<@729795837223501834>"]
```

something like that, i have declared everything and made it like a on message thing, but it doesnt quite work, any one know a fix and if you need me to specify anything feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking?Here's the way to get your bot to react to a message:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === '<@729795837223501834>') {
    message.react('');
  }
})
```

Comment: basically like when some one pings someone, itll react to the message with the reaction